# Excel column split by criteria

Tags: excel, split

I have a column with the following text:

```
PLEASANT AVENUE

PATTERSON DRIVE
```

I would like to separate the road type ("Avenue", "Drive", etc.) from the address (or road name, like "Pleasant" or "Patterson").

I need to end up with Col1 as the street name and Col2 as the type, as follows:

```
col1      |  col2
          |
PLEASANT  |  AVENUE
          |
PATTERSON |  DRIVE
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I would build a road type dictionary in this case as some of them have more than 1 word. Otherwise you could just use `RIGHT()` to extract the last word (assuming most road types are 1 word) and then join them with the rest of the field using the delimiter you want.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I will check this out and give it a try.

Comment: With respect, I am rather new.  Could you explain this a bit further?  I have streets like the above and also two word streets such as JOHN GRAY ROAD.

Comment: I am referring to the "Road Type" rather than the name with the added assumption that the street name is before the road type. If you feel confident that the road type will always be the last word in your field then you can use a formula to get it. From a quick google search: `=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)))`. Hope this helps.

Comment: formatting sample tables, and adding some clarification to desired goal

Answer (score 0):

Select the column where you have the text, then go to *Data* => *Text to column* => *Delimited* => *Space*.

Comment: Thanks for answering my post.  I cant really do this because many street names are multiple words.  The columns went everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to @nicolaesse's post, you could first replace text to create a better delimiter.

For example: replace "AVENUE" with "; AVENUE", and then use the delimiter " ; " to split into columns.

P.S. do this for "DRIVE" too